# Jquery - Get an object name and execute a method on it

Tags: jquery, html, object

I have a basic image slider on my page and some buttons to control slider movement. I'm trying to use data attributes to tell jquery which slider needs to be moved. Here's the html of buttons

```
<ul class="slider-controls">
    <li><a href="#" class="left" data-controls="hero"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="right" data-controls="hero"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

another one would be

```
<ul class="slider-controls">
    <li><a href="#" class="left" data-controls="product"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="right" data-controls="product"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the slider is initialized like so

```
var hero = $('#hero ul.slider').lightSlider();
```

To go to the next slide in the slider all I have to do is `hero.goToNextSlide();` but the `hero` part is supposed to come from html. Here's what I have for right side for the time being

```
$('.slider-controls .right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var control = $(this).data('controls');
    //move slide to right here
});
```

Now `control` would have the value "hero" but that's a string and doesn't reference the object `hero`. How can I successfully execute `hero.goToNextSlide();` from the value of `control`?

Comment: Can you post your `hero` class/object? What does it look like? What does `goToNextSlide()` look like?

Comment: If I've understood correctly: `$('#' + control + ' ul.slider').goToNextSlide()`

Comment: hero object is defined in the 3rd code snippet. It's an instance of [lightslider](sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) (plugin). goToNextSlide() method moves the slide by one to right. @kosmos you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to save the slider instance in the `data` object of the DOM element to which the slider is attached to.

```
var hero = $("#hero ul.slider").lightSlider(); 
var product = $("#product ul.slider").lightSlider();

$("#hero ul.slider").data('slider', hero);
$("#product ul.slider").data('slider', product);
```

Then, in the click handler, you would get the slider instance like so:

```
 var control = $(this).data('controls');
 var slider_obj = $('#' + control + ' ul.slider').data('slider');
```

From here, you can call any public function available in `lightslider`:

```
slider_obj.goToPrevSlide();
slider_obj.goToNextSlide();
```

So, the full code is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hero = $("#hero ul.slider").lightSlider(); 
var product = $("#product ul.slider").lightSlider();

$("#hero ul.slider").data('slider', hero);
$("#product ul.slider").data('slider', product);

$('.slider-controls .left').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var control = $(this).data('controls');

   var slider_obj = $('#' + control + ' ul.slider').data('slider');

   //move slide to left here
   slider_obj.goToPrevSlide();

 });

$('.slider-controls .right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var control = $(this).data('controls');

    //move slide to right here

   var slider_obj = $('#' + control + ' ul.slider').data('slider');

   slider_obj.goToNextSlide();

 });

});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6v8yraw2/.

Comment: That was awesome man. Thanks. I never knew you could save objects to the dom like that. Very handy

Answer (score 0):

You may try below approach:

```
//go to next slide
$('.slider-controls .right').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var controlId = $(this).data('controls');

    //move slide to right here
    var slider = $("#"+controlId + " ul.slider").lightSlider(); //grab the slider object on which we can execute the operations
    slider.goToNextSlide();
});

//go to prev slide
$('.slider-controls .left').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var controlId = $(this).data('controls');

    //move slide to left here
    var slider = $("#"+controlId+ " ul.slider").lightSlider(); //grab the slider object on which we can execute the operations
    slider.goToPrevSlide();
});
```

**Note**: assuming that your both slider are getting initialized like:

```
var hero = $('#hero ul.slider').lightSlider();
var product = $('#product ul.slider').lightSlider();
```

Comment: It works but this pretty much reinitializes the whole slider on every click of the arrow keys. I don't like that from a performance perspective. But thanks.

Comment: who told you its getting re-initializing on each click. calling `$("#"+controlId+ " ul.slider").lightSlider()` doesn't mean that the slider is getting re-initialized.

Comment: It actually gets re-initiazed. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jn7w8upr/.

Comment: agree with you @andreivictor. Generally well-written plugin should always initialize the plugin if its not already initialized else should return back the plugin object. what you say?